# Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (address, street, ...) } to deeply equal { Object (address, street, ...) } + expected - actual

Tags: express, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

**This is Object i am posting in server**

```
 let targetTestObjectToPost = {
            name : {
                name   : "something",
                middle : "something",
                last   : "something"
            },
            date_of_birth : new Date(1994,12,2),
            date_of_join  : new Date(2004,3,25),
            mail : {
                value : "something@gmail.com",
                sub   : "mobile"
            },
            phone_num :{
                value : "9832983298",
                sub   : "personal"
            },
            address : {
                    address : "something",
                    street  :  "abc street",
                    po_box  :  "abc po box",
                    neighborhood : "something",
                    zipcode : 192923,
                    city    : "city",
                    state   : "state",
                    nation  : "nation",
            },
            work_profile : {},
        };
```

**This Object i am receiving from server**

```
let targetReceiedObject = {
    __v: 0,
     date_of_birth: '1995-01-01T18:30:00.000Z',
     image: 'oaeelstctlxopxeihoo5',
     userid: '59fb5d435fd23c7b4cf64be5',
     _id: '59fb5d495fd23c7b4cf64be6',
     address: 
      { address: 'something',
        street: 'abc street',
        po_box: 'abc po box',
        neighborhood: 'something',
        zipcode: 192923,
        city: 'city',
        state: 'state',
        nation: 'nation' },
     phone_num: { value: 9832983298, sub: 'personal' },
     mail: { value: 'something@gmail.com', sub: 'mobile' },
     date_of_join: '2004-04-24T18:30:00.000Z',
     name: { name: 'something', middle: 'something', last: 'something' } } }
}
```

**When i am doing test in server ,test block look like this**

```
it('it should post employee successfully',(done)=>{
        chai.request(server)
            .post('/api/employee')
            .set('token',token)
            .send(passObject)
            .end((err,res)=>{
                if(err)
                    done(err);
                else
                {

                    res.should.have.status(200);
                    let obj =  res.body.data;
                    expect(obj.name).to.eql(passObject.name);
                    expect(new Date(obj.date_of_birth)).to.equalDate(passObject.date_of_birth);
                    expect(new Date(obj.date_of_join)).to.equalDate(passObject.date_of_join);
                    expect(obj.address).to.eql(passObject.address);
                    expect(obj.work_profile).to.equal(passObject.work_profile);
                    done();
                }
            });
    });
```

*** it is giving me test error ***

```
 Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (address, street, ...) } to deeply equal { Object (address, street, ...) }
      + expected - actual

         "neighborhood": "somethinfg"
         "po_box": "abc po box"
         "state": "state"
         "street": "abc street"
      -  "zipcode": 192923
      +  "zipcode": "192923"
       }

      at chai.request.post.set.send.end (test/employee_test.js:159:48)
      at Test.Request.callback (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:619:12)
      at node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:795:18
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/parsers/json.js:16:7)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

**server is node.js and express.js,
datbase is mongoose.**

**schema look like this**

```
name           :   {
                            name          :   {  type : String , require : true  },
                            middle        :   {  type : String , require : false },
                            last          :   {  type : String , require : true  },
                            family_name   :   {  type : String , require : false },
                            suffix        :   {  type : String , require : false }
                       },
    date_of_birth  :   {    type : Date },
    date_of_join   :   {    type : Date ,   default : Date.now },
    mail           :   {
                            value : { type  : String  , require : true } ,
                            sub   : { type  : String   }
                       },
    phone_num      :   {
                            value : { type : Number , require : true },
                            sub   : { type : String  }
                       },
    address        :   {
                            address       : { type :  String  },
                            street        : { type :  String  },
                            po_box        : { type :  String  },
                            neighborhood  : { type :  String  },
                            zipcode       : { type :  Number  },
                            city          : { type :  String  },
                            state         : { type :  String  },
                            nation        : { type :  String  }
                        },
    work_profile   :    {    type : ObjectId , ref : 'work_profile' },
    image          :    {    type : String   , require : true },
    userid         :    {    type : ObjectId , ref : 'User' , require : true
```

** I am using chai-http a test server.the responce is in json format"**

Comment: This is the most lame question that i posted . sorry people .just changed my post object value from "string" to "number"  type.